# How to import a CSV file into MySQL wtih a non-default engine

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a CSV file via MySQL. Everytime I import the file via the IMPORT tab, it creates the table in InnoDB engine. Do I import the CSV file using MyISAM?

Comment: "I import the file via the IMPORT tab". What client are you using?

Comment: A client is a software that you use to connect and execute command in the database. Just in case you don't know.

Comment: When I upload it through the Import tab, automatically it choses the InnoDB, is thee an option there to make the Engine MyISAM instead of InnoDB. I changed the table to MyISAM afterwards, but I want to see the time the engine takes.

Comment: You didn't answer what I asked. What client are you using? What is the name of the software you are using to import the CSV file? MySql is the database engine not the software you are in.